# Mean vs Expected Value

Tags: probability

I have a probability distribution like so,

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
1/(2x) & x\geq 2\\
11/40 & x=1
\end{cases}
$$

The question asks to "find the mean for X", which I calculate like so:
$\bar{x}= 1/n \cdot \displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=1}^6 x$

Which gives me, 21/6=3.5.
However, the answer to question is 2.775, which is the expected value of the above function.

Am I misinterpreting the question incorrectly? Or is the solution incorrect?

Comment: The mean of $X$ is the mean of the random variable $X$ and not the dummy variable $x$. The mean of a random variable is the same as its expected value (by definition).

Comment: I see, so I was misinterpreting the question.

Comment: If $x$ is supposed to be in the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, I think that should be stated explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\mathbb E(X) = \sum_{x=1}^6 x f(x) = \frac{11}{40}\cdot 1 + \sum_{x=2}^6 x \frac{1}{2x}.
$$

Comment: The value of the above summation is 2.775.